# Can not update or save settings on SonarQube behind Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: docker, nginx, sonarqube, reverse-proxy

I've an instance of sonarqube and nginx both in docker.
Sonarqube is behind nginx and it works fine, I can access it BUT I can not update anything in sonarqube UI such as installing plugins in Marketplace. 
When I press install or update my account details it says:

[image]

It looks like it fails to pass cookies and authentication token when making Ajax calls. When pressing install button on plugin marketplace, it makes a POST call to: `http://localhost:8089/sonarqube/api/plugins/install`

Have I missed anything in nginx config?

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    sendfile on;
      server {
        location /sonarqube {
            proxy_pass         http://sonarqube:9000;
            proxy_read_timeout  90s;
            proxy_redirect     http://sonarqube:9000 http://localhost:8089;
       }
    }
}
```

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.nginx
    ports:
      - "8089:8080"
    networks:
      - sonarnet
  sonarqube:
    build:
       context: .
       dockerfile: Dockerfile.sonarqube
    expose:
      - "9000"
    networks:
      - sonarnet
    environment:
    - SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/sonar
    - SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=sonar
    - SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=sonar
    - sonar.forceAuthentication=true
    - sonar.web.context=/sonarqube

    ########### The following line fixed the problem:###########
    - sonar.core.serverBaseUrl = localhost:8089/sonarqube
    ############################################################

    volumes:
    - sonarqubeConf:/opt/sonarqube/conf
    - sonarqubeLogs:/opt/sonarqube/logs
  db:
    image: postgres
    networks:
     - sonarnet
    environment:
    - POSTGRES_USER=sonar
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=sonar
    volumes:
    - postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
    - postgresqlData:/var/lib/postgresql/data
 networks:
  sonarnet:
   driver: bridge
......
```

**After spending a whole day, I found the solution. As sonar is behind the reverse proxy and accessible as localhost:8089/sonarqube, we need to specify sonar.core.serverBaseUrl as well. So adding the following env variable solved the problem: - sonar.core.serverBaseUrl = localhost:8089/sonarqube**

Comment: After spending a whole day, I found the solution.
As sonar is behind the reverse proxy and accessible as http://localhost:8089/sonarqube, we need to specify sonar.core.serverBaseUrl as well. So adding the following env variable solved the problem:
 - sonar.core.serverBaseUrl = http://localhost:8089/sonarqube